# Calculating "Duration" on overall workout time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with some workout data. And I'm calculating the overall workout duration.

```
const exercises = [
  {
    title: 'Abdominal Crunch',
    id: '4YRrftQysvE1Kz8XACtrq4',
    rest: ['30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '', '', '', '', ''],
    reps: ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '', '', '', '', ''],
    durationBased: false,
    duration: ['', '', ''],
  },
  {
    title: 'Bicep curl',
    id: 'sdffsdfsdfssdfsdf',
    rest: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    reps: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    durationBased: true,
    duration: ['00', '30', '00'], // HH:MM:SS
  }
];

function showTotal(total, prefix) {
  let sec_num = parseInt(total, 10); 
  let hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
  let minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
  let seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;

  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  console.log(`${prefix}: ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`)
  /* return (
      <Paragraph>
        {prefix}: {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
      </Paragraph>
    ); */
}

let grandTotal = 0
exercises.map((exercise) => {
  const totalReps = exercise.reps.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b || 0, 10), 0);
  const totalRest = exercise.rest.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b || 0, 10), 0);

  const total = totalReps * 4 + parseInt(totalRest);
  grandTotal += total
  return showTotal(total, `Total ${exercise.title} Duration`);        
})

showTotal(grandTotal, "Grand Total");
```

Rest/Reps calculation is working correctly on strength based exercises but if I wanted to add a "Duration based" exercise I cannot seem to get the logic to work.

There is a true or false if it's duration based.

The section I'm having difficulty with is the `duration` time calculation and adding that to the grandTotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `reps` is in seconds so you want seconds for both type of exercises. Then you need logic for converting HH:MM:SS to seconds and you're done

```
let grandTotal = 0
exercises.map((exercise) => {
let total = 0
if (exercise.durationBased == false) { // your current logic as it works for you
  const totalReps = exercise.reps.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b || 0, 10), 0);
  const totalRest = exercise.rest.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b || 0, 10), 0);

  total = totalReps * 4 + parseInt(totalRest);
} else {
  // guessing that you're accumulating the seconds
  total = 3600 * exercise.duration[0] + 60 * exercise.duration[1] + 1 * exercise.duration[2];
}
  grandTotal += total
  return showTotal(total, `Total ${exercise.title} Duration`); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an if statement that checks the `durationBased` property and does the logic a bit different. I more-or-less just copied your logic into the if statement.

```
exercises.map((exercise) => {
  if (exercise.durationBased) {
    const totalTime = exercise.duration.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b || 0, 10), 0);
    grandTotal += totalTime
    return showTotal(totalTime, `Total ${exercise.title} Duration`);  
  } else {
    const totalReps = exercise.reps.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b || 0, 10), 0);
    const totalRest = exercise.rest.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b || 0, 10), 0);

    const total = totalReps * 4 + parseInt(totalRest);
    grandTotal += total
    
    return showTotal(total, `Total ${exercise.title} Duration`);  
  }      
})
```